# How to get class from type parameter

Tags: scala, class, inheritance, types, case-class

Lets say we have some case class

```
case class Product (name: String, price: Int)
```

we can get its declared fields with following code

```
classOf[Product].getDeclaredFields
```

how to do the same thing if we passed Product as a type to some class

```
class SqlModels[T] {
// How to get declared fields of T here
}

val sqlInstance = new SqlModels[Product]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: May I ask why do you need this? **Reflection** is complex, unsafe, slow and should only be used as a last resource.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez
I'm just learning scala and i need it for the sake of self-education.
In this particular case i want to create class that would construct sql query text based on case class fields... What is your suggestion to solve such problem?

Comment: This kind of problems can be solved using _type-level_ programming to generate **typeclasses** at compile time. In particular, you will need to use a library called `Shapeless` to do that. However, this is a really advanced topic and I would stay away from it if you are just learning. - PS: If you are in Scala `2.13` and only want to support case classes, you can use the `productElementNames` & `productIterator`  methods on [**product**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Product.html) which all case classes extend.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thanx a lot for recomendations... No doubt they would be exttremely useful but still i'm curious about my question in topic^ is there any way to get class from T as i did it from Product

Comment: Yes `final class SqlModels[T](implicit private val ct: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T]) { val class = ct.runtimeClass }`.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, works well, thanx a lot...Actually i didnt get your warnings about this way...It looks to Me quit useful and convinient for my problem

Comment: Reflection is _"bad"_ because: It is unsafe, you can do anything with it and the compiler will not help too much, you can break contracts and produce code that will always fails in runtime. It is slow, you can search for benchmarks on internet. It will great in complexity once you start to doing more things, what if one of the fields is a collection of other classes with also have inner collections? - Finally, in **Scala** _(mainly for the reasons already stated)_ reflection is considered a bad practice, reserved to cases where its use is really necessary.